# Getting grub rescue error

Tags: grubrescue

I have deleted the ubuntu partition from my laptop and restarted the machine. Now i am getting grub rescue error as :

error : no such partition
Entering rescue mode.
grub rescue> _

I have installed ubuntu dual boot with windows 7. 
How to get Windows 7 back?
Please assist.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Boot-Repair Wiki may be of help to you

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Your boot-repair link helped me to solve my problem. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Great, glad I could help!